# Am getting an "Undefined array key " error on form output

Tags: php, validation

```
<?php
    require 'config/database.php';

    //get signup form data if signup button was clicked

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $firstname = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $lastname = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $createpassword = filter_var($_POST['createpassword'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $confirmpassword = filter_var($_POST['confirmpassword'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $avatar = $_FILES['avatar'];
        echo $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $createpassword, $confirmpassword;





    }else{
        //if button wasnt clicked then bounce back to signup page
        header('location:' . ROOT_URL . 'signup.php');
        die();
    }
```

Here is the error message:

Warning: Undefined array key "createpassword" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blog\signup-logic.php on line 11
BismarkBizzyloganlogan@gmail.comqwerty12345

i checked my html and its correct and i tried removing the "FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS" but nothing worked

Comment: Double check the spelling of createpassword that it matches in both files. You can also add `var_dump($_POST);` to check the values.